# require() gives a reference error - Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: python, html, node.js, json, flask

I am trying to send data from a javascript file to my python file. I am using flask to do so but I can't get the value from my JS file to my html template to pass it my python file. The values that are in my JS file are obtained through an EEG device which gives brain readings.

EDIT- I have tried to the browserify library  but it did not make a difference. I also tried using require.js

main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../cortex/cortex-example-master/nodejs/src/raw.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    // setup the button click
    document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
        doWork()
    };
}

function doWork() {
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.post("receiver", JSON.stringify(dataArray), function(){

    });
    // stop link reloading the page
 event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
This will send data using AJAX to Python:<br /><br />
<a href="" id="theButton">Click Me</a>
</html>
```

raw.js

```
const Cortex = require("../lib/cortex");

function raw(client, onResult) {
  return client
    .createSession({ status: "active" })
    .then(() => client.subscribe({ streams: ["eeg"] }))
    .then(subs => {
      if (!subs[0].eeg) throw new Error("failed to subscribe");

      const headers = subs[0].eeg.cols.slice();
      headers.unshift("seq", "time");
      headers.headers = true;

      let n = 0;
      const onEeg = data => {
        if (n === 0) onResult(headers);
        onResult([n, data.time].concat(data.eeg));
        n++;
      };

      client.on("eeg", onEeg);

      return () =>
        client
          .inspectApi()
          .then(() => client.unsubscribe({ streams: ["eeg"] }))
          .then(() => client.updateSession({ status: "close" }))
          .then(() => client.removeListener("eeg", onEeg));
    });
}

if (require.main === module) {
  process.on("unhandledRejection", err => {
    throw err;
  });

  const readline = require("readline");
  const stdin = process.stdin;
  readline.emitKeypressEvents(stdin);
  if (stdin.isTTY) stdin.setRawMode(true);

  const verbose = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 1;
  const options = { verbose };
  const client = new Cortex(options);
  // these values need to fill to run example
  const auth = {
    username: "prashanb",
    password: "Basti123",
    client_id: "BP9CKBpyiA0RbZqAXe7uEiDRju9m4N02e3KPWBlz",
    client_secret: "n8ymWHCgndLBSYbIn2XShGLyb6WIc8I6dBMVRb84ZFsOciVjX3KZWsgFSgPCmbkxfmMRlVtmk6NmmjjvO7H8FYvCLH4Wt3nQ2hXi4QTsO4YjSneJra6jGpTwxgPha1dx",
    debit: 1 // first time you run example debit should > 0
  };
 var eegData="hi";
 var dataArray = ["mehani"];
 dataArray.id="dataArrayId";
eegData.id="eegDataStuff";
  client.ready
    .then(() => client.init(auth))
    .then(() => raw(client, rawData => dataArray.push(rawData.join(','))))
    .then(finish => {
      console.warn(
        "Streaming raw data as CSV. Press any key to add a marker or escape to stop."
      );

      return new Promise(resolve => {
        stdin.on("keypress", (char, key) => {
          const time = new Date();
          const { ctrl, alt, meta, name } = key;
          if (!ctrl && !alt && !meta && name.match(/^[a-z0-9]$/)) {
            client
              .injectMarker({ label: "key", value: name, time })
              .then(() => {
                const ftime = `${time.toLocaleTimeString()}.${time.getMilliseconds()}`;
                console.warn(`Added marker ${name} at time ${ftime}`);
              });
          } else if (name === "escape" || (ctrl && name === "c")) {
            stdin.removeAllListeners("keypress");
            stdin.pause();
            resolve(finish());
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .then(() => client.close())
    .then(() => {
        dataArray.forEach(function (item,index,array) {
            console.log(item,index);
            JSON.stringify(dataArray);
        })
      console.warn("Finished!");
    });


  // We could use the value returned by numbers) here, but when we ctrl+c it
  // will clean up the connection anyway
}


module.exports = raw;
```

app.py

```
from requests import post

import data as data
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def output():
    # serve index template
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ['POST'])
def worker():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    result = ''
# read json + reply
    print(data)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use require function in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315987/how-to-use-require-function-in-js)

Comment: I tried including the require.js downloaded file too

Comment: Check this out too https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Comment: `require` is available for `serve-side`, you can't use it in browser engine.