# How to load a single AMD module in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to load a single AMD module using node.js.

Basically I need to check only the presence for a property in that AMD module.

I would like to know if node offers this possibility directly.
If no I would like to know a npm package which could help on the tasks, which does not change the node loader (I need a very simple solution for now).

Thanks

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Comment: This change the the node loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer such a broad question in any details.

See the resources in those answers:

- [Exporting Node module from promise result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279796/exporting-node-module-from-promise-result/41279904#41279904)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)

and you should find all the info you need.