# JS - How to dynamically import a module await it and then export the module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to dynamically import a module. But I'm not able to figure it out, how to export it correctly.

```
const calendarLocale = async () => await import(`./lang/calendar/${lang}`);

const messages = {
    [lang]: {
      ...calendarLocale()
    }
}

export default new VueI18n({
   locale: lang, // set locale
   messages, // set locale messages
});
```

Because it's asynchronous the value in messages is always empty.

Comment: I feel like stupid and I know that question was asked often, but I just cannot figure it out in my case.

Comment: do you want to reexport something taken from dynamic import?

Comment: I don't see how it can be possible to do this without having the Promise itself be the thing you export, one way or another.

Comment: you cannot do this way. details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958334/how-can-i-export-promise-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible - it would require [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), which currently is a proposal only.

All you can do is export a promise:

```
export default import(`./lang/calendar/${lang}`).then(calendarLocale => new VueI18n({
   locale: lang, // set locale
   messages: {
     [lang]: calendarLocale
   }, // set locale messages
}));
```