# Why my promise based request returns Promise object on return and expected data in console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, promise, axios

please check the below axios get request **example** to a random public api.

### Intro

I would simply like to create a function which will execute get requests and return data, so I can store the returned data in a variable and use it in the UI I am building.

Currently the function returns Promise object and not data as expected.

I also noticed that returned promise object is printed before logged data response. This makes me think that for some reason return command doesn't await the resolution of the promise.

I can use any other library apart *axios* as well, but tried *fetch* which is giving me same results.

Furthermore, I tried executing correct code from other stackoverflow answers on this topic, but it gave me same results.
Which leads me thinking my issue has something to do with my environment.

### What I already tried

- I looked into all answers on query "axios request returns undefined" and similar
- I looked into all answers on query "get data from axios request" and similar
- tried executing the code from browser using react
- changing the function to synchronous, which instead of Promise object return `undefined`

#### My env:

- System Version: macOS Monterey 12.4 (21F79)
- Kernel Version: Darwin 21.5.0
- Node@v18.7.0
- axios@0.21.4
- iterm@2

### Example

*The example can be executed by running `node script.js`.*

```
// filename: script.js
const axios = require("axios");

async function fetchApi() {
    const getRequest = await axios.get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("logged response:", response.data.count);
        return response.data.count;
    })
};

const response = fetchApi();
console.log("returned response:", response);

// execute@bash: node script.js
// returned response: Promise { <pending> }
// logged response: 1425
```

### My question

I would expect returned result and logged result to be the same.

Please help me troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to return the data, because the data doesn't exist yet. Instead, you will need to return a promise. `async` functions automatically return promises, so you're part way there, but you currently aren't returning anything from your async function. I also recommend you don't mix async/await with `.then` as it will just cause confusion:

```
async function fetchApi() {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
    return response.data.count;
};
```

To access the eventual value of the promise, you will need to put your code in an async function and await the promise:

```
async function someFunction() {
  const count = await fetchApi();
  console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: thanks @Nicholas, my aim is actually to use returned data in global context as a name for a button. So when I use your implementation and return value from someFunction it will still be a promise. I might be missing some major features of javascript and/or webdev as I am quite new to it.
Also I tried without `async`, which will return undefined instead of promise.

Comment: Yeah, it's promises all the way down. It's not possible to return a value that doesn't exist yet. async/await is a tool to simplify working with promises, but you still must use promises. If `someFunction` isn't where you're using the value, then whatever function calls `someFunction` will need to await the promise that `someFunction` returns. And the function before that will need to await a promise too, etc. This continues all the way to the code that actually uses the value.

Comment: ok thanks for all the answers. I finally managed to achieve it in react with using state and useEffect. Seems the issue was in me not understanding couple of javascript concepts...

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchApi` is an `async` function, which means it will return a `Promise`.

You should use either `await` or `.then()` syntax to execute your next actions after the Promise is resolved.

The only problem is that you can't use `await` syntax in your current implementation since you're using the result in the top level of your script file and not inside a function, Node didn't support top-level awaits in older versions.

So you should either use `.then()` syntax like this:

```
fetchApi().then( response => {
  console.log("returned response:", response)
};
```

or wrap your code inside a function if you want to use `await` syntax:

```
async function main() {
  const response = await fetchApi();
  console.log("returned response:", response);
}

main();
```

if you are using Node v14.8+ you can just use `await` inside a module:

```
const response = await fetchApi();
console.log("returned response:", response);
```

Comment: thanks @Positivity. I can already achieve this with current code. The problem arises when I want to return data into global context - I would like to pass the value as a name for some button.
Unfortunately the server is running older node. Is there a similar implementation for older versions of node?

Comment: @MihaMajcen No, I'm not aware of that, why don't you just return the Promise and wait for the resolution in your main script..
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262272/2543240

Comment: ok thanks for all the answers. I finally managed to achieve it in react with using state and useEffect. Seems the issue was in me not understanding couple of javascript concepts...