# fetch api to return actual data not promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

How do I get my getData() function to actually return the data. At the moment I get a console log of a promise object

```
function getData() {
    fetch('//some api url')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { return data })
};

export const data = getData();
console.log(data); // returns promise, not actual object
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting a promise. You should be getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just wait for asynchronous code without `await`

```js
function getData() {
  return fetch('//some api url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      return data
    })
};

getData().then(console.log)
```

```js
function getData() {
  return fetch('//some api url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      return data
    })
};

(async () => {
  const data = await getData()
  console.log(data)
})()
```

Comment: What is the point of `.then(data => { return data })` in your answer?

Comment: [Is ".then(function(a){ return a; })" a no-op for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122)

Comment: for the first solution, is there any way I can export the data out to a variable like 'data' and then use export const data to use it on another page in react js

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262272/5089567) but I'm not sure if it works in the browsers

Comment: @mathsnerd22 you should await for `fetchData()`

Comment: `async function fetchData() {
    const data = await fetch('//some url');
    return await data.json();
}

export const data = fetchData();

console.log(data) //returns promise`

Comment: I checked on codesandbox and `'await' is only allowed within async functions` so it's not possible in browsers yer

Comment: how can I go about this? i'm trying to store the data in a variable then export that variable across another reactjs page

Comment: `await` for it in the other files for example