# NodeJS - requiring module is not working synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js

From what I understand after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279796/exporting-node-module-from-promise-result) question, `require(ModuleName)` is a synchronous operation.

In the `register-rmq.js` I have written the following:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

function main(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      amqp.connect('localhost:5672', function(error0, connection) {
        if (error0) {
          throw error0;
        }
        connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
          if (error1) {
            reject(error1);
          }
          channel.assertQueue('', {
            exclusive: true
          }, function(error2, q) {
            if (error2) {
              reject(error2);
            }
          });
          resolve(channel); //
        });
      });
    })
}

main().then(function(result){
    module.exports = {result}
})
```

In my `controller.js` I have the following two lines of code:

```
var channel = require('./register-rmq');
console.log(channel);
```

What I am expecting from the code is that the line after requiring the module in `contoller.js` gives me the object that I am expecting from the module which I am requiring, however the `console.log` that I have in `controller.js` gets executed **before** the `promise` gets return and therefore the `channel` object is empty in the controller.

Is code I have written is wrong? or Am I confused about how the operation works in this context?

Comment: I've never seen someone define `module.exports` inside a promise callback, I'm not even sure what that would do. It won't work the first time the file is required, but I'm not sure if it's possible for it to be required LATER, by some later file, and have it work...

Comment: @TKoL It a node environment, it would always be an empty object.

Comment: @TKoL, Thank you, you are right. I did not know the correct way to export it and I thought the right place to do so is inside the callback.

Comment: @George actually I've just tested it, and that's not true. It is NOT always an empty object. If you define `module.exports` in one file after a 30 second promise callback, and you require that file from a different file after a different 30 second promise callback, it actually works in the second file!

Comment: There's obvious reasons why that's not the correct way to do it, but it is possible to require a module export defined asyncronously.

Comment: @TKoL Right you are, apologies. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already highlighted that exporting a module is done synchronously; you can't wait until a promise is resolved (or, any asyncronous operation) and expect the correct value to be exported synchronously.

The most appropriate pattern in this scenario would be the following.

**register-rmq.js**

```
module.exports = main();
```

**controller.js**

```
var channel = require('./register-rmq');

channel.then(result => console.log(result));
```