# Is it ok to use Babel npm package for node.js server application

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

As Node V6 already supports ~95% of ES6, why are people using Babel on the server side? What are the pros and cons of using Babel on the server side?

Comment: I'm quite sure it's ok to do but for the most part unnecessary.  It may be a carry over from working with the browser and folks not realizing it's not needed on node. I can't say for sure though and hence this is a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442290/is-it-ok-to-use-babel-npm-package-for-node-js-server-application/42442403#42442403) below answer your question? Any comments?

Answer (score 3):

There is one main reason: `import` / `export`

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

There is even a special Babel preset for Node:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node6

that doesn't transpile anything that Node already supports natively.

You can also use `babel-preset-env` which is "A Babel preset that can automatically determine the Babel plugins and polyfills you need based on your supported environments" - thanks to **loganfsmyth** for pinting it out in the comments. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-env

And Node doesn't support ES6 modules - see this answer for details on why:

- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)

Comment: These days the community has mostly moved from `babel-preset-node6` to `babel-preset-env`.