# What is the syntax to export a function from a module in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the syntax to export a function from a module in Node.js?

```
function foo() {}
function bar() {}

export foo; // I don't think this is valid?
export default bar;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Comment: Absolutely not a duplicate. This is a matter of feature support in the current Node build. What's with the downvotes, people?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Node you export things with `module.exports` special object. For example:

This exports both functions:

```
module.exports = { foo, bar };
```

They can be used as:

```
const { foo, bar } = require('./module/path');
```

To export one of those functions as top-level object you can use:

```
module.exports = foo;
module.exports.bar = bar;
```

which can be used as:

```
const foo = require('./module/path');
```

and:

```
const { bar } = require('./module/path');
```

or:

```
const foo = require('./module/path');
const { bar } = foo;
```

or:

```
const foo = require('./module/path');
const bar = foo.bar;
```

etc.

This is "the syntax to export a function from a module in Node.js" as asked in the question - i.e. the syntax that is natively supported by Node. Node doesn't support `import`/`export` syntax (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271) to know why). As **slezica** pointed put in the comments below you can use a transpiler like Babel to convert the `import`/`export` keywords to syntax understood by Node.

See those answers for more info:

- [Is it ok to use Babel npm package for node.js server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442290/is-it-ok-to-use-babel-npm-package-for-node-js-server-application/42442403#42442403)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)

Comment: Ah, thank you. And what is the ES2015 module syntax for the same?

Comment: This is the only way until Node starts supporting `import`/`export` ES6 syntax, **which it currently does not**. You can also use Babel, installing `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-latest` as dev-dependencies, then precompiling your javascript or running `babel-node`. I do this for all my projects

Answer (score 3):

to expose both foo and bar functions:

```
module.exports = {
   foo: function() {},
   bar: function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
export function foo(){...};
```

Or, if the function has been declared earlier:

```
export {foo};
```

Reference: [MDN export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in a shorter form

```
// people.js
function Foo() {
  // ...
}

function Bar() {
  // ...
}

module.exports = { Foo, Bar}
```

Importing:

```
// index.js
const { Foo, Bar } = require('./people.js');
```