# node.js es6 export / import with index.js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following folder structure

```
src/
  index.js
  lib/
    test.js
dist/
examples/
  example.js
```

src/lib/test.js

```
export default class Test {}..
```

src/index.js

```
import App from './lib/test.js'
export default App
```

examples/example.js

```
import {App} from './../..'

=> App is undefined
```

How can I set my index.js as entrypoint and export my app there?

edit:
I'm using babel-node as transpiler and start it with

```
nodemon test.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2 --watch ./../..
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `from '../src'` instead of `from './../..'`?

Comment: And you’ve shown us `export class Test`, but not a default export. I don’t think `export {default as App}` would be valid to do that anyway…?

Comment: You're exporting default but importing named export App - which doesn't exist.

Comment: @estus thanks now it's not undefined anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `import` and `export` is not natively supported by Node.

You need to use a transpiler like Babel if you want to use that syntax.

The Node way is to use `module.exports` and `require()`.

See this for more info:

- [Is it ok to use Babel npm package for node.js server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442290/is-it-ok-to-use-babel-npm-package-for-node-js-server-application/42442403#42442403)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)
- [What is the syntax to export a function from a module in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171890/what-is-the-syntax-to-export-a-function-from-a-module-in-node-js/45171950#45171950)

### Update

Here:

```
export {default as App} from './src/lib/test.js'
```

you're not exporting "from" - you import from.

Maybe you meant:

```
import App from './src/lib/test.js';
```

and then you can export that in turn.

With normal Node syntax it would be:

src/lib/test.js

```
class Test {
  // ...
}
module.exports = { Test };
```

src/index.js

```
const { Test: App } = require('./lib/test.js');
```

examples/example.js

```
const { App } = require('../src');
```

Also note that according to your directory structure your paths are incorrect: it should be `./lib/test.js` instead of `./src/lib/test.js` and  `../src` instead of `./../..`

Comment: But then the OP would get a syntax error, not `undefined`, no?

Comment: I'm using babel-node as transpiler to start it with "nodemon test.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2 --watch ./../.."

Comment: @coffeecup It would be much easier to answer your questions if you included the relevant info in the question in the first place.

Comment: I changed export class to "export default" in my test.js file, and changed the export from.. to import test from in my index.js, now when I console.log(test) I can see [Function: App].

How would I export this properly to be able to import it in my example.js?

Comment: my index.js is import Test from ..... and export default Test, but in my example.js it's still undefined

Answer (score 1):

I would just put src/index.js as main in the package.json and just run nodemon without the watch param.

> By default nodemon monitors the current working directory. If you want to take control of that option, use the --watch option to add specific paths

Also paths sould look like this:

src/lib/test.js

```
export default class Test {}
```

src/index.js

```
export {default as App} from './lib/test.js'
```

examples/example.js

```
import {App} from '../'
```