# React, how to import components from folder index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a little component library I am trying to build out. So it made sense to put them in a folder and only import the ones I need or all at once if needed using the import * from folder.

It looks a little something like this.

```
 /sliceZone
 |--index.js
 |--newsBlock.js
```

This is how I'm exporting my component in newsBlock.js:

```js
export default NewsBlock;
```

Inside my index.js in the sliceZone folder I have:

```js
export { NewsBlock } from './newsBlock';
```

and inside the file Im working on I am trying to import it like:

```js
import { NewsBlock } from './sliceZone';
```

But I'm getting the error in my terminal

```sh
warn "export 'NewsBlock' was not found in './sliceZone'
```

How do I export components from a `index.js` file?

Comment: How did you export the component from newsBlock.js? Coz if there is a named export the example should work. If there is a default export it won't work.

Comment: This is how I'm exporting my component in newsBlock.js:
export default NewsBlock;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js es6 export / import with index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174856/node-js-es6-export-import-with-index-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

In index.js

```js
import NewsBlock from './newsBlock';
//Anything else to import from the folder.

export { NewsBlock, /*Anything else to export*/ };
```

then when I import into another file I can use.

```js
import { NewsBlock, /*Anything else*/ } from './sliceZone/';
```

Answer (score 2):

On your `index.js` file you should try

```js
export {default as NewsBlock} from './newsBlock';
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a default export, you need not destructure it in import statements. So if you have

```
export default NewBlock;
```

You can import it using

```
import NewsBlock from ./newsBlock;
import Anything from ./newsBlock;
```

Both above statements are valid. And `NewsBlock` and `Anything` imports will have NewsBlock.

If you export object as below

```
export NewsBlock;
```

Then you must destructure it to use.

```
import {NewsBlock} from ./newsBlock;
```

Not sure if it is something you are looking for, but just felt it is related information and may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

inside `newsBlock.js` you can write `export default NewsBlock ;` and you can import that from `import { NewsBlock } from './sliceZone';` or `import { NewsBlock } from './sliceZone/index';`